# How will I print the highest scorer (with it's other "struc mates") using a function. C

Tags: c

Beginner in C here, please bear with my question since I am having a hard time explaining it. And I'm really sorry if my terms are incorrect. I hope you get it.

Say that I have my struct like this:

```
struct studentType
{
       char studentFName[20];
       char studentLName[20];
       int score;
       char grade;     
}s[20];
```

and I have inputted 3 elements in to `s`. Now I have compared each others score, 
through this:

```
void getHighestScorer(struct studentType s[20])
{
     int maximum, i;
     maximum = s[0].score;
     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
      if (s[i].score > maximum)
      {
       maximum = s[i].score;             
      }
     }    
}
```

and I have found that `s[2]` has the highest score compared to the others. How will I actually print that one on another function with its other "struc mates"

I actually tried doing it on the function above like this(and it didn't work):

```
void getHighestScorer(struct studentType s[20])
{
     int maximum, i;
     maximum = s[0].score;
     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
      if (s[i].score > maximum)
      {
       maximum = s[i].score;             
      }
     } 
     printf("The highest scorer is: %s, %s %d\n", s[i].studentLName,s[i].studentFName,  
              s[i].score);
}
```

My whole program is [here](http://pastebin.com/SDJr7f42)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is you are iterating over array till index 3 (i<3) and hence i value at the end of loop would always be 3. So maintain index of last max item.

```
void getHighestScorer(struct studentType s[20])
{
 int maximum, i, index = 0;
 maximum = s[0].score;
 for(i=1;i<3;i++)//should start with 1 as 0 you are considering is max
 {
  if (s[i].score > maximum)
  {
   maximum = s[i].score;          
   index = i;   
  }
 } 
 printf("The highest scorer is: %s, %s %d\n", s[index].studentLName,s[index].studentFName,  
          s[index].score);
}
```

Hope this is what you are after.

If you want to pass this struct in another function, change this method to return the index and in that method accept your struct and index (that above function would pass) and use your same printf statement that should work.

Comment: Yes! That is what I've been looking for. Though, may I add another question? How will I actually print that in another function? Do I have to use pointers?

Comment: Remember to initialize `index` to 0 before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Define the function the following way

```
int getHighestScorer( struct studentType s[], size_t n )
{
     int maximum;
     size_t i;

     if ( n == 0 ) return 0;

     maximum = s[0].score;

     for ( i = 1; i < n; i++ )
     {
         if ( maximum < s[i].score ) maximum = s[i].score;             
     }

     return maximum;    
}
```

and use it like

```
printf( "Maximum score is %d\n", getHighestScorer( s, 3 ) );
```

Or another approach

```
size_t getHighestScorer( struct studentType s[], size_t n )
{
     size_t maximum = 0;
     size_t i = 1;    

     for ( ; i < n; i++ )
     {
         if ( s[maximum] < s[i].score ) maximum = i;             
     }

    return maximum;    
}
```

And use it like

```
size_t i = getHighestScorer( s, 3 );
printf("The highest scorer is: %s, %s %d\n", s[i].studentLName,s[i].studentFName,  
          s[i].score);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "struc mates"?
If it means you want to print the other members of the struct along with the score member,
then the following should help:

```
void printHighestScorer(struct studentType s[20]) //this the function wherein I don't know what to put//
{
    int maximum, i;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    maximum = s[0].score;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if (s[i].score > maximum)
        {
            maximum = s[i].score;
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The highest scorer is: %s, %s %d\n", s[maxIndex].studentLName,s[maxIndex].studentFName,  
          s[maxIndex].score); 
}
```

Basically you need to store the index of the struct variable which contains the maximum score.